# Astra Linnux 1.3 + Apache 2.2 + Kerberos

Tags: apache2, kerberos

Добрый день!

Открывая в Firefox localhost/ выскакивает ошибка 500 internal server error

в error-логах ошибка:

> [crit] [client 192.168.50.1] configuration error:  couldn't perform authentication. AuthType not set!:

Файл /etc/apache2/sites-available/default:

```
    <VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin admin@ald.astra.ru
ServerName ald.astra.ru
DocumentRoot /var/www
<Directory />
    AuthType Kerberos
    KrbAuthRealms REALM
    KrbServiceName HTTP/ald.astra.ru@ASTRA.RU
    Krb5Keytab /etc/apache2/keytab
    KrbMethodNegotiate on
    KrbMethodK5Passwd off
    Require valid-user
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
<Directory /var/www/>
    AuthType Kerberos
    KrbAuthRealms REALM
    KrbServiceName HTTP/ald.astra.ru@ASTRA.RU
    Krb5Keytab /etc/apache2/keytab
    KrbMethodNegotiate on
    KrbMethodK5Passwd off
    Require valid-user
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
<Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride None
    Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

# Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
# alert, emerg.
LogLevel warn

CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
```

Настойки произведены в соответствии п. 6.8.3. РУСБ.10015-01 95 01-1
Astra Linnux 1.3 Smolenks
Apache2 2.2
Krb5
Вопросы: 
1. Почему сервер не видит тип аутентификации?
2. Как это исправить

Comment: http://itsecforu.ru/2017/02/15/apache-%D0%B0%D1%83%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-kerberos/

Answer (score 1):

/etc/apache2/sites-available/test.lc.conf :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        ServerName test.lc
        ServerAlias www.test.lc test.lc
        DocumentRoot /var/www/test/
        <Directory /var/www/test/>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride None
                AuthType Kerberos
                KrbAuthRealms DOMAIN.COM
                KrbServiceName HTTP/ald.domain.com
                Krb5Keytab /etc/apache2/keytab
                KrbMethodNegotiate on
                KrbMethodK5Passwd off
                KrbSaveCredentials on
                require valid-user
        </Directory>
        ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/oerror.log
        LogLevel debug
        CustomLog /var/log/apache2/oaccess.log combine
</VirtualHost>
```

Выполнить

```
sudo a2ensite test.lc.conf
sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-auth-kerb
sudo a2enmod auth_kerb
```

рестартануть апач

В `/etc/hosts` добавить на сервере и клиентах
`192.my.serv.ip  www.test.lc test.lc`

В файрфоксе каждом! заходим `about:config` и в опцию `network.negotiate-auth.trusted-uris` вписать `http://test.lc` , перезапустить

Зайти на клиенте за пользователя домена(!) с явно определёнными метками безопасности(!!), открыть браузер и перейти на сайт.

*UPD* Тестировалось на 1.6

Для включения сквозной аутентификации в `Chromium` нужно создать директорию `/etc/chromium/policies/managed`, куда поместить файл `test.json` с содержимым:

```
{
    "AuthServerWhitelist": "test.lc"
}
```

Для `Firefox` - в файл `/etc/firefox/firefox.js` дописать

```
pref("network.negotiate-auth.trusted-uris","test.lc");
```